# javascript array is being read before creating items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created a section including all its content using JS.

```
const  main = document.querySelector('main') ,
    new_p = document.createElement('p'),
    new_h2 = document.createElement('h2'),
    new_div = document.createElement('div'),
    new_section = document.createElement('section')

main.appendChild(new_section);
new_section.id = ('section4');
new_section.appendChild(new_div);
new_div.classList.add('landing__container');
new_div.appendChild(new_h2);
new_div.appendChild(new_p);
new_h2.textContent = 'Section 4';
new_h2.id = 'heading4';
new_p.textContent = 'some text goes here'
```

Then I made an array of all sections (previously created using HTML and newly created using JS).

```
const sections = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("section"))
```

The problem is that array gets only the sections created with HTML only and can't see the ones created with JS.

here is the array logged to the console (the 3 items in the array are already created with HTML)

```
(3) [section#section1.your-active-class, section#section2, section#section3]
```

Anyone can help me how to detect newly created sections with JS?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code and it's working. JS has no problems here. Maybe you are trying to access sections before the new one is added.
See this snippet:

```js
const  main = document.querySelector('main') ,
    new_p = document.createElement('p'),
    new_h2 = document.createElement('h2'),
    new_div = document.createElement('div'),
    new_section = document.createElement('section')

main.appendChild(new_section);
new_section.id = ('section4');
new_section.appendChild(new_div);
new_div.classList.add('landing__container');
new_div.appendChild(new_h2);
new_div.appendChild(new_p);
new_h2.textContent = 'Section 4';
new_h2.id = 'heading4';
new_p.textContent = 'some text goes here'

const sections = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("section"))
console.log(sections);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- <script type="module" src="./async-await.js"></script> -->
    <script type="module" src="./script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section id="section1"></section>
        <section id="section2"></section>
        <section id="section3"></section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree with you It's working fine and the new element appears in browser. – 
But it's not being added to the array. I need to find a method to add the newly created sections to the array

Comment: But inside my snippet, it is added to the array. Run my snippet and see

Comment: I can't understand how it works in the snippet and doesn't work at my side.
I know that JS checks the array before creating section 4 but I don't know how to avoid that.